# Pass variable from one function to another function inside same PHP class file

Tags: php, function, class, variables

Similar questions exists - I've tried already some solutions from StackOverflow and Google but still no luck - I can't catch a right syntax.
I have PHP class file (PHP 7.4) with

```
public function indexAction()
{
    if ($this->req->get('lang')) {
        $lang = $this->req->get('lang');
        file_put_contents('/var/www/html/app/controllers/control_indexaction.php', $lang); // selftest OK
        // with every change of layout control file changes accordingly to en de it etc
        // so $lang variable actually works and exists here
    } else {
        $lang = 'en';
    }
}
    
public function searchAction()
{
    $page = $this->req->get('page');
    $q = $this->req->get('q');
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/app/controllers/control_searchaction.php', $lang); // for selftest
    // other code of function - everything works
    // where no $lang variable
}
```

The problem is I need to pass variable `$lang` from function `indexAction()` to use under function `searchAction()` - If I just copy same line

```
$lang = $this->req->get('lang')
```

from function `indexAction()` to function `searchAction()` - it does not work, no any output, so `$lang` variable actually exists only under function `indexAction()`.

Would be obliged for any hint to try pass of variable `$lang` under this case.

Comment: Use a class property: `$this->lang`

Comment: If you mean to set under second function searchAction() - `$lang = $this->lang;` - such a syntax does not work, control file still empty...

Comment: In `indexAction()` you need to say `$this->lang = $this->req->get('lang');` and in `searchAction()` you can use `$this->lang`. If that still doesn't work, it's probably because you're not calling `indexAction()` before `searchAction()`.

Comment: Why doesn't `$this->req->get('lang')` work in the second function? Are you calling the methods on the same object?

Comment: Tried to use `$this->lang = $this->req->get('lang');` under first indexAction() but anyway under second function `$lang = $this->lang;` does not produce an output to control file - AND indexAction() calls BEFORE searchAction() - it's own control file changes on every reload.
YES, simple copy of `$this->req->get('lang');` does NOT work in the second function, I can't explain why, no any errors.

Comment: This is why I've simplified my question as much as possible with control files - and I acknowledge I can't catch a right syntax, so I hope somebody will give a complete example how it's possible to pass variable $lang from first indexAction() to second searchAction()

Comment: If it doesn't work the way it *should* work, you'll either have to debug that or resort to an alternate method like storing it in a global variable.

Comment: To my regret I setup full report of any PHP errors for debug - but the problem is that no errors...it would be easier if an error exists...will try to read about global variable, but again afraid abt my own syntax errors, I'm not PHP developer, I just can make some small adoptions.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a controller in an MVC setup? Are the two methods invoked by separate requests? Then you can't pass anything within the class, the data needs to be present within the request.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.  You need a local variable in the class that both functions can access.

```
protected $lang = '';

public function indexAction()
{
    if ($this->req->get('lang')) {
        $lang = $this->req->get('lang');
        file_put_contents('/var/www/html/app/controllers/control_indexaction.php', $lang); // selftest OK
        // with every change of layout control file changes accordingly to en de it etc
        // so $lang variable actually works and exists here
    } else {
        $this->lang = 'en';
    }
}

public function searchAction()
{
    $page = $this->req->get('page');
    $q = $this->req->get('q');
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/app/controllers/control_searchaction.php', $this->lang); // for selftest
    // other code of function - everything works
    // where no $lang variable
}
```

Comment: And if $this->req->get('lang') this was supposed to be the same variable, then you dont need to use get.  just $this->lang everywhere inside the class.